# Ubuntu 22.04 libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to symbol 'gdk_window_hide'

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, undefined, lib, gdk

I have this link error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to symbol 'gdk_window_hide'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I just wonder which library has this symbol? I have libgtk-3-dev installed.

```
ii  libgtk-3-dev:amd64                                          3.24.33-1ubuntu2                           amd64        development files for the GTK library
```